# When i refresh page I see only last JSON file instead of view

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I use Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core (Application created from template).
My website works normally but when I click F5 to refresh or I change page up to 10 sec after start application I see only last received JSON as text instead of view like that [image]. 
Any clue where should i look for source of this bug?

EDIT: Now i see that after F5 I get message in console Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:61829/movies".

My movies.component.html (this problem occurs on every single page of my website)

```
<h2> Nowy Film </h2>

<div>
    <ul>

    <li><label>Tytuł</label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="movie.title" required/></li>
    <li><label>Rok</label><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="movie.year" max="2017" min="1900" value="2000"/></li>
    <li><button (click)='addMovie()'> Dodaj </button>
    </ul>
</div>

<h1>My Movies </h1>


<p *ngIf="!movies"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<div class="card-deck-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="card-deck">

       <div class="card" *ngFor="let movie of movies">
            <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="card-block">
               <table style="width:100%">
                   <tr>
                       <th width="60%"><a [routerLink]="['/movie-detail',movie.id]" class="card-title">{{movie.title}} </a></th>
                       <!--<th>Edit</th>-->
                       <button (click)='deleteMovie(movie)'> Delete </button>
               </table>
               <p class="card-text">{{movie.year}}</p>
               <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"></small></p>
           </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

movie.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Movie} from './movie';
import {MovieService} from './movie.service'
@Component({
    selector: 'movies',
    template:  require('./movies.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./movies.component.css')],
    providers: [MovieService],

})

export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit{
    movies:Movie[];
    movie: Movie;
    constructor(
       private movieService:MovieService,
    ){
        this.movie=new Movie();
    }
    addMovie():void{
        this.movieService
        .addMovie(this.movie)
        .then(movie =>this.movies.push(movie));
    }
    ngOnInit():void{
        this.getMovies();
    }
    getMovies():void{
         this.movieService
        .getMovies()
        .then(movies=>this.movies=movies)
        .catch();
    }
    deleteMovie(movie:Movie):void{
        this.movieService.deleteMovie(movie.id)
        .then(movies=>this.movies=this.movies.filter(m=> m!==movie));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, add more details/code.

Comment: Check your network tab to see if you are requesting something unusual.

Comment: Post your `/movies` relevant TS and HTML files please.

Comment: I feel like /movies is your api address to get the movies list.

When you refresh a Angular2 app, if the route is not the index.html route and you haven't set up your server to redirect everything to index.html, it's not gonna fire  up your Angular2 app and normally is gonna show a `Page Not Found or 404 or ...` or something like that.

BUT , in your case , instead of showing page not found, it shows the /movies from your api, because that route exists in your api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it happens because of [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#!#browser-url-styles). When using it angular construct normal looking urls like `site.com/route` and your backend does not know that this url should be handled by angular hence it tries to serve it itself. You need to setup `ASP.Net Core` so that it will handle all routes with default controller and angular will open appropriate component on the client.

Please check [this](https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2015/05/a-tale-of-angular-html5mode-aspnet-mvc.html) or [this](https://benjii.me/2016/01/angular2-routing-with-asp-net-core-1/).

Also it looks like your api endpoint is the same as your client page url: `localhost:.../movies`. Usually all api endpoints are perpended with some prefix (eg `/api`). In this case endpoint will become `localhost:.../api/movies`. Otherwise it can be tricky to setup proper routing on the server.

Comment: Yep, i had to add api/ to all routes. Now everything works fine. Thank you.